# Handling print event on Electron

Tags: javascript, printing, electron

Am new on Electron and I need to create POS Desktop app which call a localhost web application and make silent printing. 
And because the printing event is called from inside the web-app I think the way is to handle the printing event from BrowserWindow and overwrite it by call `webContents.print({silent: true...`
But i can't find soution on net so if there is a better way please help

this is my code

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
function createWindow () {
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
  mainWindow.webContents.loadURL('http://localhost:40/');
}
})
```

Comment: Are you going to make print the browserWindow contents at some specific event?

Comment: If so, when are you going to print the contents?